# Use Hazelcast Executor Service to be executed on clients

Tags: client, hazelcast, executorservice

I all the documentation and all the "Google search results" I saw, the hazelcast executor service can be used to be executed on "Members". 
I wonder if it is possible to also have things being executed on hazelcast clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributed executor service is intended to run processing where the data is hosted, on the servers. This is a similar idea to a stored procedure, run the processing where the data lives, save data transfer.

In general, you can't run a Java `Runnable` or `Callable` on the clients as the clients may not be Java.

Also, the clients don't host any data, so they'd have to fetch what data they need from the servers potentially.

If you want something to run on all or some connected clients, you could implement this yourself using the publish/subscribe mechanism. A payload could be sent to an `ITopic` with the necessary execution parameters, and clients listening can act on the message.

Comment: Thank you,I thought so and already developed into the direction of Topics. Just making sure there is no "simpler" way in our use case.

Comment: @wildnez's answer is also helpful. If you have to run an executor on clients, and can use a _near-cache_ (client's side cache of server data) that can reduce network calls, if you can tolerate that near-cache may be slightly stale.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Near Cache on client side and use JDK’s ExecutorService that runs in your local jvm app.